# How to display UICollectionView inside static TableViewCell?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uicollectionview

I want to display `UICollectionView` inside static `TableViewCell`

I have a static `TableViewCell` that contains `CollectionView`. Well, the problem is that, in my opinion, code looks good but when I launch program, `TableViewCell` doesn't show me CollectionView. I'm a little bit confused, so I will be so happy if you help me. Thanks

*TableViewController Class:*

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    var Cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Action")
    switch indexPath.section {
        case 0:
            tableView.register(ScheduleCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "Schedule")
            Cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Schedule") as! ScheduleCell

        case 1:
            return Cell!

        case 2:
            tableView.register(MarksCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "Marks")
            Cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Marks") as! MarksCell

        default:
            Cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Action") as! ActionCell
    }

    return Cell!
}
```

*ActionCell:*

```
extension ActionCell: UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout, UICollectionViewDataSource {
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 3
    }

    func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "ActionCell", for: indexPath) as! ActionsCollectionViewCell
        var Labels = ["РАСПИСАНИЕ", "ДОМАШНИЕ ЗАДАНИЯ", "ОЦЕНКИ"]
        var Icons = ["Safari", "DZ", "Rating"]
        var Colors = [UIColor.init(red: 26/255, green: 196/255, blue: 234/255, alpha: 1),
                  UIColor.init(red: 251/255, green: 143/255, blue: 25/255, alpha: 1),
                  UIColor.init(red: 251/255, green: 25/255, blue: 118/255, alpha: 1)]
        cell.Title.text = Labels[indexPath.item]
        cell.Icon.image = UIImage.init(named: Icons[indexPath.item])
        cell.Button.backgroundColor = Colors[indexPath.item]
        return cell
    }
}
```

Also, I have to notice that in Storyboard i mentioned all classes and ReuseIDs

Comment: Did you set `delegate` and `datasource` of collectionview ?

Comment: Yes, I did it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using 'UITableView' with Static Cells as a content you don't need to implement 'tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)' everything can be defined in Storyboard.

Here's how the UITableViewController would look like in storyboard, using custom cells (TableCell, CollectionCell) both for table and collection view, and having 'UITableViewCell'
 act as a data source for containing 'UICollectionView':

[image]

And here's UITableViewController implementation:

```swift
class ViewController: UITableViewController {

}

class TableCell: UITableViewCell {

}

class CollectionCell: UICollectionViewCell {

}

extension TableCell: UICollectionViewDataSource {
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "collectionCell", for: indexPath)

        return cell
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 1
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried to use your solution but I got this error: **'-[UITableViewCell collectionView:numberOfItemsInSection:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x106057200'**. Sorry for the mistakes, i'm feeling so ashamed. My code is here: https://imgur.com/a/ONYziql

Comment: Have you set the dataSource to be your custom 'ActionCell'? Here's my sample project for [reference](https://www.dropbox.com/s/p3l5n7ewkhcqnbb/sdsd.zip?dl=0)

Comment: I found mistake! Thanks a lot. I'm a real idiot. Wishing you a Happy New Year